# Descending Order With ngx-order-pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to sort Array by both `ascending` and `descending` order. I have done with Ascending but I don't have to sort by descending order using `ngx-order-pipe`.

1. `$ npm install ngx-order-pipe --save`
2. **TS**

   ```
   dummyData: any[] = [
       { name: 'G' },
       { name: 'B' },
       { name: 'Z' },
       { name: 'A' },
       { name: 'H' }
   ];
   ```
3. **HTML**

   ```
   <div *ngFor="let item of (dummyData | orderBy:'name') ">
       <p>{{item.name}}<p>
   </div>
   ```

Any Idea how to do Descending Order?

Answer (score 3):

There is one argument called `reverse`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (dummyData | orderBy:'name' : true) ">
    <p>{{item.name}}<p>
</div>
```

In HTML template

```
{{ collection | orderBy: expression : reverse : caseInsensitive : comparator }}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (dummyData | orderBy:'name':reverse) ">
  <p>{{item.name}}<p>
</div>
```

TS:

```
reverse: boolean=false
sort() { // call this on click function where you will trigger sorting
this.reverse=!this.reverse
}
```

This will help you to toggle between Ascending and Descending.